# Pandas: select string with unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, pandas

I am trying to select rows by specifying the value of one of the columns. That works perfectly well, as long as the value selected is pure ascii. If however, it contains non-ascii characters, I cannot get it to work no matter how I encode the value.

Simplified example to illustrate the problem:

```
>>> from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, 
                            print_function, unicode_literals)
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Stuttgart'], [2, 'München']], columns=['id', 'city'])
>>> df['city'] = df['city'].map(lambda x: x.encode('latin-1'))
>>> store = pd.HDFStore('test_store.h5')
>>> store.append('test_key', df, data_columns=True)
>>> store['test_key']
   id       city
0   1  Stuttgart
1   2    M�nchen
```

Note that the non-asci string is indeed properly stored:

```
>>> store['test_key']['city'][1]
'M\xfcnchen'
```

Selecting for asci value works just fine:

```
>>> store.select('test_key', where='city==%r' % 'Stuttgart')
   id       city
0   1  Stuttgart
```

But selecting for the non-ascii value fails to return the row:

```
>>> store.select('test_key', where='city==%r' % 'München')
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, city]
Index: []

>>> store.select('test_key', where='city==%r' % 'München'.encode('latin-1'))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, city]
Index: []
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong... How does one solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, selection seems to work fine if the encoding is utf-8 instead of latin-1:

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, 
                        print_function, unicode_literals)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Stuttgart'], [2, 'München']], columns=['id', 'city'])
df['city'] = df['city'].map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'))
store = pd.HDFStore('/tmp/test_store.h5', 'w')
store.append('test_key', df, data_columns=True)
print(store.select('test_key', where='city==%r' % 'Stuttgart'.encode('utf-8')))
#    id       city
# 0   1  Stuttgart

print(store.select('test_key', where='city==%r' % 'München'.encode('utf-8')))
#    id     city
# 1   2  München

store.close()
```

Comment: Ok, I am filing this under "weird". ;-) Given that utf-8 encoding works, it is easy enough to work around the "weirdness". And as an added bonus, even the output formatting of pandas works with utf-8! Thank you very much for pointing out this fix.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PyTables 3.1.1 may not support unicode columns.  I'm not a PyTables user but this [bug report](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/268) suggests it is a known problem postponed until version 3.2.  This [other issue](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/268) is maybe relevant.

Comment: Thanks but I am not storing unicode at all. I use normal string columns and store ascii encoded unicode. I.e. not "München" directly but "M\xfcnchen". Consequently, it should be possible to query for this ascii string. I looked at the bug report but as far as I see they are dealing with unicode columns rather than string column which store ascii encoded unicode. - Please let me know if I misunderstood you.